# Appropriate HTTP Status Code for "Too Soon to Renew JWT Token"

Tags: http-status-codes

I want an API to reject renewing a JWT auth token if the user is trying to renew it too early.

What would be an appropriate HTTP status code to return? I looked into 425 but I wasn't 100% sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say, 412 Precondition Failed,

or the common 403 Forbidden

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [429](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6585#section-4) (Too Many Requests).